# How to track return path in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

When I investigate code in Eclipse I do something like:

```
method1() {

  method2(a,b,c);
```

......

I select method2 and push F3:

```
method2(int a,String b, long c ){

 method3();
```

......

I select method2 and push F3:

```
method3() {
   ....
  method4(....
```

Sometimes chain can be near 10 items! Does exist some shortcut to go back? So I could return to previous point where I was been?

P.S. I know Ctrl+Q for last editing, but this is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> traverse the history of navigations (at least on Linux.)

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is use `Call Hierarchy` in eclipse, via right click method and select `Open Call Hierarchy`, then it will open out a Call Hierarchy View for you to navigate.

As @Alexander Pavlov suggested, you can use Alt + Left / Right to navigation

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> takes you back to the previous location.

Answer (score 1):

In the debug perspective you can see your entire stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

option+command left and option+command right for OS X. I was SOOOOOOO happy to see Eclipse had this built in.

Still not as slick as Xcode...